# Why is my Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown invisible?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown, nav

I have the correct code and I'm using the correct CSS and JS links in the HEAD. I cannot fathom why this dropdown is not working.  The downwards arrow renders but nothing happens when the user clicks.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid d-lg-flex">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Largs Model Boat Club Logo" style="width:200px;"></a>
    <h1 class="display-1">Largs Model Boat Club</h1>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbartogg">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-lg-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="news_uc.html">News & Events</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="aboutlargs_uc.html">About Largs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbartogg" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Aside from the color issue, your code works fine. Please revise the snippet demo so it shows your problem.

Comment: In which way should I revise it?  I cannot see why the dropdown won't render.  The code SHOULD work fine, but it is not.  The background color of my header is a blue i have defined in external CSS.  I do not wish a dark background, which is why I did not include it.

Comment: Basically include the css styles and anything else that is necessary to reproduce the problem. Right now if we click "Run code snippet" in your question all we see is a white navbar where everything is invisible because the text color is also white. We can't help if we can't reproduce the problem you describe.

Answer (score 1):

you just misplaced the color of the background, you can simply add `bg-dark` or remove `navbar-dark`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid d-lg-flex">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="Largs Model Boat Club Logo" style="width:200px;"></a>
    <h1 class="display-1">Largs Model Boat Club</h1>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbartogg">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-lg-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="news_uc.html">News & Events</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="aboutlargs_uc.html">About Largs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbartogg" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```